# Field inside object which extends App trait is set to null. Why is that so?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm trying to use scalatest to test an App like this:

```
object Main extends App {
    val name = "Greg"
}

class JunkTests extends FunSpec with MustMatchers {
    describe("Junk Tests") {
        it("Junk-1 -- Must do stuff") {
            println("Name: "+Main.name)
            // some test here
        }
    }
}
```

My name output is always null.  How can I get my main object going to use its facilities during a test?  In actual use I have an App that's an Http server and I want to send it messages, but right now its never initialized so the server is never started.  This simple example shows that Main is never initialized.

Answer (score 14):

> It should be noted that this trait is implemented using the
>   DelayedInit functionality, which means that fields of the object will
>   not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

[*Scaladoc for App trait*](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App)

So you can either:

- define val as final: `final val name = "Greg"`
- trigger main method before accessing name field
- define name as method: `def name = "Greg"`
- define name as `lazy` val: `lazy val name = "Greg"` (so in this case, as well as in previous, there is no matter in which order initialization is done)

Comment: making the val lazy worked for me; making it final did not change the behavior.